# Customizing the windows server 2008 RDP login screen possible?

Tags: windows-server-2008, login, rdp

I'm working with RDP sessions quite frequently. As we work in teams and all use the same user account on a particular computer (I know...) I was wondering if there was a way to display from which computer (hostname, computername) the person is connecting.
The login screen I get when two users are already connected looks like this (german):

[rdp login http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/6f44b0fad1.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/6f44b0fad1.png)

I'd love it, if the screen would display from where the logged in user is connecting e.g. "COMPUTER\user connected from MYCOMPUTERNAME". This way I would know whom to ask to disconnect so I can hop onto the session.
If I remember correctly the login screen looked different for previous Windows versions including this connection information. Any way I can easily enable this or is this just standard windows behavior and there is no way to tell from where the user is connecting (btw: Task Manager shows the computername of the connected user).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recently started using [Remote Desktop Connection Manager](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=4603c621-6de7-4ccb-9f51-d53dc7e48047&displaylang=en), and once if its features is that you can right click on a server and list the sessions it has open.

This will tell you the session status, the username and also where they are logged in from - giving you a clue as to who you can ask to disconnect

The list sessions feature works on Server 2003, as well as 2008 R2. I don't have any 2008 boxes to test against, but I assume it will work without issue there too.

Comment: RDCman is useful, but yet it is another tool I would need to use - I have tried it as it was released, but think there are better (more mature) remote desktop managers available. Good to know you can list the sessions though.
I was really asking about the standard login screen of Server 2008 or 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

doubt you can change it.  Also, i don't believe windows 2003 showed you this information either. It showed the same information, only difference was it was shown in a listbox.
Not even the terminal services manager console shows you the host the user is logged in from.

Maybe you can sneak in via the backdoor & connect to the [console](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/278845) & use taskman to figure out who to boot? Or maybe it's time you finally consider using more then one login.

Comment: yes to console and yes to more than one login - I was just wondering whether there was a different way